# Growing form when opened with acDialog

Tags: forms, ms-access, dialog

I open a form with that command:

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmGraphData", acFormDS, , , , acDialog, "A" & Me.OpenArgs

When I created the form I save it in the size I want it. But the form grows every time I open it. After a while the bottom of the form just goes below the screen!!

It's not modal and not an independant window

I'd like to force the form to keep its original size. How can I do that?

Thank's

Comment: is there any code to dynamically change the size of the form?

Comment: Absolutely not. The code inside the form just put value in some variable. Nothing about the format of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest (*possibly the flakiest*) way to deal with this is to set the form width on the open event.  [This](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1624335-i-need-open-form-specific-size.html) will do the trick but may give the dev behind you anger management issues.

```
    Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
        DoCmd.MoveSize , , 6000, 6000
    End Sub
```

Comment: If this is the answer go ahead and hit that check mark to mark it as the answer.  Thanks,